# What's the play event on a video html5 element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I have a video html5 tag embedded on page. I need to trigger an action when the user clicks the "Play Button". But I can't find how to bind that to my action. Is there an event for what I need? I'm using jQuery...

Thanks!

Comment: But you want to trigger new event on button click? Or you want to bind to `play` event of `<video>`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Does this W3C demo page help? http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html It appears the play event is simply 'play'.

For example:

```
$('video').bind('play', function (e) {
    // do something
});
```

or

```
$('video').on('play', function (e) {
    // do something
});
```

Answer (score 8):

I used code from the following [page](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html) and stripped it:

```
<script language="javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

    function init() {
        var _video = document.getElementById("video");
        _video.addEventListener("playing", play_clicked, false);
    }

    function play_clicked() {
        alert("play was clicked");
    }
</script>

<video id='video'
  controls preload='none' 
  poster="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/poster.png">
  <source id='mp4'
    src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4"
    type='video/mp4'>
  <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
</video>
```

Hoped I could help.

Comment: The demo page in your answer is pretty cool and shows the events and data that can be collected from the video player.

Answer (score 7):

HTML5 Video elements have an `onplay` event that you can use that doesn't require the extra step of adding a listener. This solution also doesn't require JQuery.

```
var myVid = document.getElementById('video');    
if (myVid !== null) { // Possibility of no video loaded in DOM
    myVid.onplay = function () {
        //do something
    };
}
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onplay) has full details.