# How to start/play a wordpress acf oEmbed video with a seperate button?

Tags: wordpress, video, advanced-custom-fields, oembed

I've created an acf wordpress field with the type: "oEmbed". Now I have to implement an seperate Button to show and hide the included video in the frontend.

Everthing is working fine, but I would like to start/play the video if I click on the button and when it is shown.

Is there a parameter to edit this behaviour via javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the play event on a video html5 element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680432/whats-the-play-event-on-a-video-html5-element)

Comment: No, I do not use the "video" tag. I use oEmbed acf field which creates an iframe.

Comment: Oh, that's right. Then see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443578/youtube-iframe-api-how-do-i-control-a-iframe-player-thats-already-in-the-html - http://jsfiddle.net/8R5y6/